# Scooter Powerband Spiking

Tags: maintenance, scooter

When I start accelerating, at around 3 seconds in, I get a spike in my engine rpm (at least it sounds like it) for a few seconds after which it calms back down and continues escalating as expected.

I don't have much knowledge of the mechanics but i'd assume it's a roller or belt problem? What would be the issue and the suggested maintenance procedure/fix?

My scooter is 150cc, around 3 months old and has just over 2000 KM on it.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as though the clutch may be slipping during engagement.  Depending on the brand there are ways to adjust the automatic clutch to engage at a lower RPM.

Answer (score 2):

Open up the variator and check the rollers. You will need an impact wrench or a holding tool to get the flywheel cover off. The variator is in the front of the transmission. When you inspect the rollers, look for cracks or flat spots. While you're in there, check the belt as well. Order new rollers just in case, they're less than $20. The cheapo ones that come with some scooters can be defective, and you can also change the weights to make the bike perform differently.

Either way it sounds like a trans problem. Try changing the driven gear oil as well.